# Display action as dropdown on specific rows using Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel-nova

After I create an action and use `onlyOnTableRow` flag, it's being displayed as a button and is displayed on every single row. That button's purpose is to change status of a row from `pending` to `approved` or `declined`. Now, I would like to use dropdown instead of button so I wouldn't have two buttons (one for `approve` and another for `decline`) and also I would like to display this button or at least make it enabled only for those rows where status is `pending`, otherwise the button/dropdown should be disabled (or hidden, doesn't matter).

```
// ApproveVacation.php
class ApproveVacation extends Action
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;

    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
        foreach($models as $model) {
            $model->update([
                'status' => 'approved'
            ]);
        }
        return Action::message('Successfully approved!');
    }

    public function fields()
    {
        return [];
    }
}

//Vacation.php
class Vacation extends Resource
{
   ...
   public function actions(Request $request)
   {
      return [
         (new ApproveVacation())->onlyOnTableRow()
      ];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I solved this. I couldn't find a way to insert dropdown into row, but this solution is close enough:

```
// ApproveVacation.php
class ApproveVacation extends Action
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;

    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
       foreach($models as $model) {
          $model->update([
             'status' => $fields->status
          ]);
       }
       return Action::message('Status has been successfully updated!');
    }

    public function fields()
    {
       return [
          Select::make('Status')->options([
             'approved' => 'Approve',
             'declined' => 'Decline',
          ])->default(function ($request) {
              return 'approved';
          })
       ];
    }
}

//Vacation.php
class Vacation extends Resource
{
   ...
   public function actions(Request $request)
   {
      return [
         (new UpdateVacationStatus())->onlyOnTableRow()->canSee(function ($request) {
            if ($request instanceof ActionRequest) {
                return false;  
            }

            return $this->resource instanceof Model && $this->resource->status == 'pending';    
        })
    ];
   }
}
```

This code will add button which displays modal on click. In modal there will be one field, it is `Status` and it will be dropdown (cause it's set to be `Select` type).

Also, to avoid displaying the button for each field, I've added condition inside `actions` function. It is checking once passed parameter is of type `Model` that would mean that parameter represents a row from a table and only than you can check for other conditions you need (for me it was to check if `status` is `pending`)